# Jupyter Notebook Error: display nothing on "http://localhost:8888/tree"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I open jupyter notebook from CMD like this,
[cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KqCK.png).
But it displays nothing and remains blank after I refresh the page for multiple times or restart the machine, like
[chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VVnK.png).
I install my Python interpreter and pip from the offcial (not anaconda) and then install jupyter notebook using pip. The version info about them is
[ver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGcbc.png).
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0

I had the same problem. It is a bug in the latest update to jupyter notebooks. The workaround is to downgrade back to the most recent working copy. I really wanted a way that used conda and not pip to downgrade, and I found an excellent solution. Anaconda keeps an archive of previous releases of the entire system (conda + jupyter + spyder + ...). You can find the archive here:

https://repo.continuum.io/archive/

For me, the version that worked was the July 2019 release

https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-2019.07-Windows-x86_64.exe

First you must uninstall Anaconda completely and then install the archived version.

Comment: it works. thx!!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are getting this error " http://localhost:8888/tree" where you can't find any of your files. I was having the same problem. When I dig into the details found out I was using notebook version 6.0.3 and the latest version at the moment was 6.3.0. This happens when you update few of the packages and Jupyter notebook version is not updated. After it took me a minute to solve the error.

**Solution:** Just go to anaconda prompt and update your notebook by typing the command

```
pip install --upgrade notebook
```